# NSString sizeWithFont line spacing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-text, uifont

I have a UITableView where each cell uses Core Text to draw some text. When calculating the height to return for heightForRow, I use NSString sizeWithFont to determine the height of the cell. However, in my Core Text drawing, I'm increasing the space between every line by a few decimals.

The question is, how can I make up for this in my heightForRow method sizeWithFont to also factor in line spacing besides the default font line spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Core Text to draw the text, you should use Core Text to calculate the height of the text.  Check out the `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` function.

Comment: Can I use this without a current graphics context?

Comment: Yes.  You can create a CTFramesetter without a CGContext.